# Squeaky Headset - Giant Fastroad SL-1 2019

Tags: headset

The headset area on my bike has just developed a squeak whenever the handlebars are turned.

I've checked that there's not friction from a cable making the noise, and the bolt on the top of the headset is properly torqued.

There is no noticeable feeling of friction or roughness when turning the handlebars.

The noise seems to be coming from the bottom of the black part that can be seen rotating with the handlebars in the attached video.

Does this require maintenance? If so, what needs to be done?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds very much like plastic rubbing on something.

Since you’ve ruled out the cables the only thing I can think of are the headset bearing seals. I’d take out the fork and check the headset bearings. Won’t hurt in any case and it’s relatively quick and easy to do (assuming your cables and hydraulic hoses are long enough). Just make sure you re-install the stem properly and set the bearing preload.

Comment: And cover them in grease!